# Cant figure out how to flip normals on this Space suit Helmet

Tags: normals, 3d-printing

I downloaded this space suit helmet here https://www.cgtrader.com/items/3165630/download-page and I was planning on 3D printing it. I cannot cut it into sections without converting the normals using other modelling software.

See a blend file here>
[image]

Ive tried using the clean up mesh tools and also the recalculate mesh tools.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that, rather than being a problem with the Normals, it’s actually a problem with Z-fighting - where the inner and outer surfaces of the mesh are touching or overlapping. The red showing through is actually the backface of the inner surface of the helmet.

To 3d-print you would need significant addition thickness in your mesh (otherwise you won’t have sufficient material) so you will need to edit your mesh to move the inner surface of the helmet away from the outer.